# Write local ip address to text file using batch file

Tags: batch-file, command, cmd, ip

I want to create a batch file that writes the local IP address on a txt file. When i run a batch file with this code (file path is wrong but that's not the problem):

```
ipconfig | find "IP Address" > \File.txt
```

I get the whole windows IP configuration (I changed some numbers and stuff with xxx to not show all info)

```
    IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : 100.100.100.223

    IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

I want to write to a file only `100.100.100.223`.

I'm new to batch files and i really searched a lot and I'm really confused. (maybe i'm searching with wrong keywords).

Forgot to tell I'm using Windows XP (Because some of the answers doesn't work on XP).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Read the just written file's first line into a variable using the `SET /P` command, then overwrite the file with that line using `ECHO`:

```
ipconfig | find "IP Address" > \File.txt
< \File.txt SET /P first_ip=
ECHO %first_ip%> \File.txt
```

---

UPDATE (in answer to comments):

To extract just the IP address, you could use a `FOR /F` loop like this:

```
ipconfig | find "IP Address" > \File.txt
< \File.txt SET /P first_ip=
FOR /F "delims=: tokens=2" %%I IN ("%first_ip%") DO (
  ECHO %%I> \File.txt
)
```

A `FOR /F` loop allows you to process text (a file or a string literal) line by line, splitting each line into fields (or *tokens*) based on the specified delimiter(s). You can read more about this command in the built-in help (`FOR /?`). I'll only add that in this case the processed piece is a string literal (the value of `first_ip`), the delimiter is set to `:`, and the loop variable (`%%I`) receives the 2<sup>nd</sup> token, which is an IP address.

Note that the space between `:` and the IP is preserved, i.e. it becomes part of the token ( `100.100.100.223`) and, therefore, gets written to the file too. If you aren't very happy about it, you could use a subroutine to get rid of the space, like this:

```
ipconfig | find "IP Address" > \File.txt
< \File.txt SET /P first_ip=
FOR /F "delims=: tokens=2" %%I IN ("%first_ip%") DO (
  CALL :MyEcho %%I
)
:: the following command is there merely to
:: avoid running (into) the subroutine again
GOTO :EOF

:MyEcho
ECHO %1> \File.txt
```

When the subroutine is called (`CALL :MyEcho %%I`), the argument is passed along with the leading space. But when processing the subroutine's command line, that space is no longer seen as part of the value, because the argument is not quoted and so the parser sees merely an argument separated from the name with two spaces. Thus the `%1` in the subroutine evaluates to the address *without* the leading space.

Comment: One more thingy, with this i print 
"        IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : 100.100.100.223"
,  can i somehow change it to only 
"100.100.100.223"

Answer (score 8):

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%a in ('ipconfig^|find "IPv4 Address"') do (
set ip=%%a
goto :BREAK
)

:BREAK
echo %ip: =% >ip.txt
```

Comment: This is so helpful! More than the answer that was marked "correct"!

Comment: This one is correct, not the marked one

Answer (score 1):

If you are OK with powershell, try this:

```
powershell.exe -c "gwmi Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration | ? { $_.IPAddress -ne $null } | % {$_.ipaddress[0]}"
```

Comment: I got a little confused here (i'm generally newbie), i'll check this one also and see what i'll get! Thanks a lot.

Comment: & off course, you would need to redirect the output to File.txt. Not added in my code.

Comment: When using powershell anyways, why still do the horrible parsing? Simply use: `Get-NetIPAddress | % { $_.IPAddress }`

Comment: ^^Giving me `The term 'Get-NetIPAddress' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.` on Win7. But yes, there are better options available. I had added this answer long ago, when I dod not know about the alternatives... Updating the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use autohotkey.

For Message box,

```
msgbox, %A_ipAddress%
```

Or if you want in text file User

```
Fileappend, %A_ipaddress%. Ip.txt
```

Helpful link. https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/45109-how-to-get-my-ip-address/