# Remove whitespace/trailing

Tags: batch-file

I'm executing the following command to write the current IPv4 address to a logfile:

```
ipconfig | findstr IPv4>>"c:\ip.log"
```

However, there are some whitespaces, how can I remove those?:

```
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.15
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.16.0.15
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.15
```

Thanks.

Comment: Related: [Write local ip address to text file using batch file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13856398/write-local-ip-address-to-text-file-using-batch-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%a IN ('ipconfig^|findstr "IPv4" ') DO (
 FOR /f %%c IN ("%%b") DO ECHO ++%%c++
)

GOTO :EOF
```

Naturally, the `echo` could be a `set` if you so desire. The `++` either end of the data is merely to show that the spaces have been removed.

Find the target line(s) from an `ipconfig` command, select that part beyond the `:` on those lines, and process the resultant string, removing ant spaces (default delimiters in the `for /f %%c`)

Answer (score 0):

This is a nice command you could use: http://fart-it.sourceforge.net/
You would use it to find and replace the part that is waste for your purpose.

**Edit**
If you want stick with the commands available, then i think you would best use this: [How to replace substrings in windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5273937/how-to-replace-substrings-in-windows-batch-file)

Look at Andriy M's first answer.

Comment: thanks dannl, but I'd prefer to use commands default to Windows only and not any external tools.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use `ECHO` and `FOR` to try something like this:

```
        ipconfig | findstr IPv4>>"c:\ip.log"
        < "c:\ip.log" SET /P my_first_ip=
        FOR /F "delims= tokens=2" %%I IN ("%my_first_ip%") DO (
        ECHO %%I>"c:\ip.log"
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell:

```
get-wmiobject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -filter 'IPEnabled=TRUE' |
  select-object -expandproperty IPAddress | out-file "C:\IP.log" -append
```