# Remove whitespace/trailing inbetween

Tags: batch-file

This might be a stupid question, but now I'd also like to remove whitespace/trailing inbetween (see also: [Remove whitespace/trailing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28723781/remove-whitespace-trailing)).

For example, I've this command:

```
fltmc volumes | find ":">>out.log
```

Which will give me output like:

```
C:                              \Device\HarddiskVolume1                  NTFS        
F:                              \Device\HarddiskVolume5                  FAT
```

How can I make it be output like this for example?:

```
C: \Device\HarddiskVolume1  NTFS        
F: \Device\HarddiskVolume5  FAT
```

Thank you..!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run the command through a `for /F` loop:

```
for /F "tokens=1-3" %%A in ('fltmc volumes^|find ":"') do echo %%A %%B %%C>>out.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Try appending to your pipeline

```
|sed -e 's/\s\s*/ /g'
```

Comment: Hi Dinesh, thanks for your answer, but I don't want to use external tools if possible. You have another idea? cheers